# Update badge on tab navigator after change in mobx store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, mobx-react

We are trying to update the badge count in a react-navigation `BottomTabBar` every time we update the store values. It is successfully updated when we update the cart when going from one page to the next, but if we try to update the cart on that same page, the badge is not changed, but as soon as we click on another tab, the value is changed to the correct up-to-date value. Is there a way to have this value change automatically as soon as the store is updated? Since the router is not a class component, we are unable to wrap it with a mobx observer.

This is where we declare our stack navigator for the tabs in `router.js:`

```
export const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
   'Home': {
        screen: Home,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'Home',
            tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (<View><Icon name="home" color={tintColor} type="light" size={22}/></View>),
            header: null,
        },
    },
    'Items': {
        screen: MenuNav,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'Menu',
            tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (<View><Icon name="utensils" color={tintColor} type="light" size={22}/><View></View></View>),
            },
    },
    'Cart': {
        screen: Checkout,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'My Order',
            tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
                <View>{store.draft.quantity ?
                    <View>
                        <View style={{position: 'absolute', top: -10, left: -10, backgroundColor: store.theme.primary_button_color, width: 20, height: 20, borderRadius: 50, zIndex: 100,}}>
                            <Text style={{ color: store.theme.primary_button_text_color, position: 'relative', left: 7, top: 4, fontSize: 10}}>{store.draft.quantity}</Text>
                        </View>
                        <Icon name="shopping-bag" color={tintColor} type="light" size={22}/>
                    </View> : <View><Icon name="shopping-bag" color={tintColor} type="light" size={22}/></View>}
                </View>),
            },
    },
    'Info': {
        screen: Info,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'Restaurant',
            tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (<View><Icon name="map-marker-smile" color={tintColor} type="light" size={22}/><View></View></View>),
        },
    }
},
    {tabBarComponent: (props) => {
        return (
          <TabBar
            {...props}
          />
        );
      },
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    },
);
```

This is how we are rendering our tabs:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BottomTabBar } from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
import globalScss from "../styles.scss";

class TabBar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BottomTabBar
                {...this.props}
                activeTintColor={'#898989'}
                inactiveTintColor={'#FFF'}
                style={[{ height: 60, paddingTop: 7 }, globalScss.primary_color]}
            />
        );
    }
}
export default withNavigation(observer(TabBar));
```

Comment: did you end up finding a solution for this?

Comment: @H.Epstein Unfortunately not, we are actually revisiting this now and still haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using navigation params instead of mobx state.

```
defaultNavigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
tabBarIcon: () => {
            rootStore.setNavigation(navigation);
            const {routeName} = navigation.state;
             if (routeName === 'Tab') {
                const badgeCount = navigation.getParam('badgeCount',0)
                return (
                    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row',alignItems: 'center',justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                        <IconBadge
                            MainElement={
                                <View style={{
                                    width:30,
                                    height:30,
                                    margin:6
                                }}
                                >
                                    <Image
                                        source={require('../../assets/Icons/tab_icon-01.png')}
                                        style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}/>
                                </View>
                            }
                            BadgeElement={
                                <Text style={{color:'#FFFFFF'}}>{badgeCount}</Text>
                            }
                            IconBadgeStyle={
                                {
                                    width:20,
                                    height:20,
                                    backgroundColor: '#F20779',
                            }}
                            Hidden={badgeCount === 0}
                        />
                    </View>
                );
            } },
}),
```

i set the navigation with in the mobx store :

```
 setNavigation(navigation) {
     this.navigation = navigation
}
```

then I update the navigation param with :

```
setBadgeValue =() => {
    if (this.navigation !== null)
    this.navigation.setParams({badgeCount: this.pendingItems.length});
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also update the badge in the Notification tab using DeviceEventEmitter in React Native... You just need to emit when notification tapped and then addListener in Badge component class to update count in the badge.

In the notification class:

```
DeviceEventEmitter.emit('updateBadgeCount',  {count:value})
```

In Badge component class:

```
DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('updateBadgeCount', this.updateBadgeCount.bind(this))

updateBadgeCount(c) {
 
   notificationCount = c.count

   this.forceUpdate() 

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also update badge in Notification tab using DeviceEventEmitter in React Native.. You just need to emit when notification tapped and then addListener in Badge component class to update count in the badge.

Comment: You copied the previous answer